# PHP refreshing using jQuery doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I wanted to create a function in javascript/jQuery, that uses php script to refresh some data on my website. I'm using it like this:

```
function aval()
{
...
$("#dost").load("readadmin.php?date="+dzien+"&diff="+diff+"&dtyg="+d);
setTimeout(aval,200);
}
```

where #dost refers to some div at the end of my site

Then, my readadmin.php file looks like this:

```
    <?php

    $diff=$_GET["diff"];
    $name = $_GET["date"];
    $dtyg = $_GET["dtyg"];

    $plik = fopen("myfile","r");
    $tekst = fread($plik,filesize("myfile"));
    fclose($plik);
    $bookings = explode(";;;;", $tekst);

    for ($i=0; $i<(sizeof($bookings)-1); $i++)
    $data[$i] = explode(":::",$bookings[$i]);

    echo "<script>";
    // here I'm echoing some javascript code, that basically changes styles on my page, 
//depending on my variables and data from a file
    echo "</script>";

    ?>
```

Also, on my site (admin.php) I use login, so my site looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered('pass'))
header('location: login.php');

?>
...html code
```

login.php:

```
 ..something not important, forms to get $_POSTs etc..
<?php
    if ($_POST["login"] == $login && $_POST["pass"] == $pass)
        {
            session_register('login');
            session_register('pass');
            header("location: admin.php");
        }
    ?>
```

Now, everything works great on Chrome or Firefox, but not on IE. When I change data in my file, IE doesn't react to this, and keep displaying old data. When I put session_start() and session_destroy() at the begining and end of readadmin.php, then data is refreshing properly, but whatever action I do, it logs me out. Nothing strange here, I start a new session every 200ms so I get kicked.

One more thing: when I'm changing data that goes to readadmin.php from site, it displays proper data back, and then immediately changes to old data.

Please help.

Comment: Use of session_register() is deprecated http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add timestamp to url so the browser will not cache the file:

```
$("#dost").load("readadmin.php?date="+dzien+"&diff="+diff+"&dtyg="+d+"&t="+Date.now());
```